# PHP writing date to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I make a request to the database, get the desired values ​​and write them to another table.
Problem is that this date will not be recorded.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Date, Name FROM table_a WHERE id='1');
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $myrow['Date'];  ====> 2014-06-01
echo $myrow['Name'];  ====> Vasja

Date colum type Date not null

mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table_b(Name, Date) VALUES ('$myrow['Name']', '$myrow['Date']')");
```

Result in my table is:

```
id     Name        Date  

1     Vasja     0000-00-00
```

Comment: ("SELECT Date, Name FROM table_a WHERE id='1'); - missing last ". Should be ("SELECT Date, Name FROM table_a WHERE id='1'");

Comment: Just do `mysql_query("insert into table_b (Name, Date) select (Name, Date) from table_a");`, optionally with a `where` clause.

Comment: just curious why is the column named Date when you know date is a datatype. Also why are you using mysql* extensions , when they had been deprecated . Try shifting to PDO or mysqli

Comment: I write from the 3 tables into one. I wrote that for example, would be easier to understand. The only problem is the date everything else he writes.

Comment: So basically you trimmed down your code to code that actually works. How about showing your actual code?

Comment: Hello user3687063 please provide some feedback regarding whether the code is working or not.

Answer (score 4):

Try using this. Since date is the datatype of sql so to omit it use `` operator. Also you have problem in concatenating the query string.

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table_b(Name, `Date`) VALUES ('".$myrow['Name']."', '".$myrow['Date']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion it's always more save to concatenate mysql strings in php.
 try this:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table_b(Name, Date) VALUES ('".$myrow['Name']."', '".$myrow['Date']."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your query because I think you have an error.

`mysql_query("SELECT Date, Name FROM table_a WHERE id='1');`

should be

```
mysql_query("SELECT Date, Name FROM table_a WHERE id='1' ");
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I write from the 3 tables into one. I wrote that for example, would be easier to understand. The only problem is the date everything else he writes.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to update Name & Date as string.

Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_b (Name, Date) 
    VALUES 
    (
        '".$myrow['Name']."', 
        '".$myrow['Date']."'
    )";

mysql_query($query);
```